# How to process HIPAA 834 EDI File?

Tags: xml, parsing, text-processing, text-parsing, edi

I have to parse and validate HIPAA 834 EDI file. I have found out a tool "EDI Validator" for this at http://www.etasoft.com/ev.htm

However, I am unable to get sample HIPAA X12 834 EDI file which can be processed with this tool from the internet.

Please help me in getting that sample file. Is there any better tool than mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a sample 834 file: [PDF](https://www.wellcare.com/WCAssets/corporate/assets/Claims_BenefitEnrollment_Guide.pdf)

It is missing the ISA and GS envelopes, but if you are unfamiliar with EDI enveloping you might want to do a little more research.  (Please note, this was the 2nd result from Googling "sample 834 edi file".  There's many more results)

Another tool I use frequently is [EDI Notepad](http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad).  This will give you a few different views of the data to help give you some context.

There are hundreds of translators out there.  What are you doing with the parsed data? Converting it to XML? Inserting it into a DB?  Do you need to generate a 997?

You should start here:  [Delta](http://liaison.com/products/transform/delta)

Comment: `834 sample file is corrupted.. Can you add the file again?` from a "answer"  of Mike Siret

Comment: ISA*00*          *00*          *12*ABCCOM         *01*999999999      *101127*1719*U*00400*000003438*0*P*>
GS*PO*4405197800*999999999*20101127*1719*1421*X*004010VICS
ST*834*0179
BGN*00*1*20050315*110650****4
REF*38*SAMPLE_POLICY_NUMBER
DTP*303*D8*20080321
N1*P5*COMPAN_NAME*FI*000000000
INS*Y*18*030*20*A
REF*0F*SUBSCRIBER_NUMBER
NM1*IL*1*JOHN DOE*R***34*1*0000000
PER*IP**HP*2138051111
N3*123 SAMPLE RD
N4*CITY*ST*12345
DMG*D8*19690101 *F
HD*030
DTP*348*D8*20080101
REF*1L*INDIV_POLICY_NO
SE*16*0179
GE*1*1421
IEA*1*000003438

Comment: Found via another Google search.  http://www.1edisource.com/learn-about-edi/transaction-sets?tset=834