# How to Parse a flatfile in Unix / Bash and create another file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

Please see data in the flatfile below 
1. Any Line start with ~INS , this is Line Separator
2. Data after 'REF*0F*'  is member (10000123)
3. Data after 'NM1*IL*1*' is Last name (TEST_LASTNAME) , First name(TEST_FIRSTNAME)
4. Data after 'DMG*D8*' is YYYYMMDD(19030330),Gender (F)
5. Data after 'DTP*356*D8*' is YYYYMMDD(20980101)
6. Data after 'DTP*357*D8*' is YYYYMMDD(20990801)
7. Data after 'N3*' is address (1007 ST VILLAGE PLACE APT 3G)
7. Data after 'N4*' is city,state,zipcode (BOSTON,MA,11233)

### ***INPUT***

*~INS*Y*18*030**A~REF*0F*10000123~REF*1L*854107MAAD10~REF*17*001~REF*23*H0423-UE14362M~REF*F6*6CX4MD3DY76~REF*3H*220070101-20201231~REF*ZZ*10020070101-20201231~DTP*356*D8*20080101~DTP*338*D8*20080101~DTP*339*D8*20090228~NM1*IL*1*TEST_LASTNAME*TEST_FIRSTNAME****34*068784265~PER*IP**TE*7183455619~N3*1007 ST VILLAGE PLACE*APT 3G~N4*BOSTON*MA*99999~DMG*D8*19030330*F~HD*030**PDG~DTP*348*D8*20980101~DTP*349*D8*20990228~REF*XX1*001~COB*P***6
~INSY*18*030**A~REF*0F*10000516~REF*1L*854107MAAD10~REF*17*001~REF*23*H0423-UE14362M~REF*F6*6CX4MD3DY76~REF*3H*220070101-20201231~REF*ZZ*10020070101-20201231~DTP*356*D8*20090801~DTP*357*D8*20990801~DTP*338*D8*20090801~DTP*339*D8*20391231~NM1*IL*1*WOOD*DAMION****34*068784265~PER*IP**TE*7183455619~N3*1704 CROSSING DR*APT 3G~N4*WESTWOOD*NY*99999~DMG*D8*19330330*M~HD*030**PDG~DTP*348*D8*20090801~DTP*349*D8*20391231~REF*XX1*001~COB*P**6***

***OUTPUT***
*10000123~TEST_LASTNAME,TEST_FIRSTNAME~19030330,F~20980101~20990801~1007 ST VILLAGE PLACE APT 3G~BOSTON,MA,99999

10000516~WOOD,DAMION~19330330,M~20090801~20391231~1704 CROSSING DR*APT 3G~WESTWOOD,NY,99999*

Comment: As somebody closed this question, I edited the question providing an answer with sed, but it is visible only for me until it's been approved by trusted community members. I think it is a very specific and focused question, and my answer could provide guidance about how to approach problems this way.

Comment: Probably you should state the format you are trying to parse is [HIPAA ANSI 834 File Layout](https://getworkforce.com/ansi-834-file-layout/) This will make your question title to look more focused. Also,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470892/how-to-process-hipaa-834-edi-file is asking a similar thing, but more generally, as they wanted to process the whole format. Your need here was more specific IMO.

Comment: [Try my solution online!](https://cutt.ly/XyvOr3Y) I hope it provides you some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You will be miserable trying this in Bash.  Use an open source EDI parser, like "bots" that you can compile for any major OS:  http://bots.readthedocs.io